# “Error during storage.set: Quota exceeded” in chrome extension developing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage

```
var bk = new Bookmark();
bk.link=blink;
bk.title=btitle;
bk.tags=["11","22"];
for(var i=0;i<20;i++)
{
bks.push(bk);}
chrome.storage.sync.set({"bookmarks":bks});
```

I'm developing a simple chrome extension. I use chrome.storage to store data,because it can save objects. when I store a small array,it get “Error during storage.set: Quota exceeded",the size of the array is so small and I had set "unlimitedStorage" in permissions.
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*","cookies","storage","unlimitedStorage"]
Can anyone help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

unlimitedStorage is only applicable for client-side storage. chrome.storage.sync has a storage limit of only 100kb, and only 4kb for each item.

Comment: really appreciate for your reply. I change chrome.storage.sync.set to chrome.storage.local.set, and it's done!!!!

Comment: @neversion did storage.local work for you? is storage.local asynchronous/non-blocking?

Comment: It is today 8 kB for each item. Helps a bit for some purposes. See: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#properties